# Ruby on Rails - "Add 'gem sqlite3'' to your Gemfile"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I was following the Rails tutorial, but I got stuck when it said to type `rails server` in the blog directory. It states

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile.

I quit the server, installed sqlite3, reinstated the server, only to get this message again. sqlite3 doesn't show up when I do `gem list`, but I do see the folder in my Root Ruby directory.

How can I fix this error?

I'm using Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0, sqlite3 1.3.7.

Comment: Could you please extend your question which operation system do you use? I guess, you use Win7, there is a little trick with sqlite3...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem Solved!

Turns out, it was several different problems:

1. I previously overlooked that sqlite3 needed to be installed in order to run, as stated in rubyonrails.org's Getting Started guide. The guide gave me a link to sqlite.com, from which I needed to download the command shell and the dll, both are under "Precompiled Binaries for Windows". More on this below.
2. The gem install gave me an error that stated it couldn't download anything from rubygems.org. Turns out, there was a new version of rubygems I wasn't aware of. Fixed with gem update --system.
3. I tried gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby, but to no avail. It couldn't build a native extension and couldn't find sqlite3.h.
4. I had asked my question also on ruby-forums. 
   http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4415126
   Here, a Joel Pearson(virtuoso) provided the missing files that I needed via attachment, since these files are not provided in sqlite.com. I followed his instructions, including putting the shell and dll files in my root Ruby's bin directory...and it worked!

So basically, I was able to install sqlite3 without modifying any Gemfile or Gemfile.lock. My gem list shows sqlite3 (1.3.7) and Rails's Welcome screen now appears as the Getting Started guide shows!
I use Windows 7-64 bit, Ruby 2.0, Rails 4.0 and I now got sqlite3 1.3.7.

Thank you very much everyone for giving this n00b advice and direction. I find that having explored the Gemfiles as well as my root Ruby directory, I understand how Ruby and Rails are fit into my computer better.

As a beginner, I would recommend being able to download the sqlite3 files and folders needed to install it on Windows both on rubyonrails.org's Getting Started guide and in sqlite.com.

Thanks again!
hewhocomes

Comment: I'm curious to know if you progressed further in the tutorial without any other issues. Did you have a problem getting rspec working?

Comment: I'd like to add that I got it working using only the '--with-opt-dir=' parameter, using the files provided by Joel. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 30):

In my case, this error `"Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'sqlite3' to your Gemfile."` message showed up, when I ran `rails server` right after I generated a fresh rails app. It was with Rails version 4.1.16 (Ruby version 2.3.1)

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.0'
```

This line in Gemfile removed the error message. I think new sqlite gem (version 1.4) has a conflict with old rails (version 4.1) but I didn't see any related issue on their Github repository. I'm adding this answer here because it might help anybody experiencing the same situation I'm in.

Comment: I just saw there was a closed issue for this actually https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/247

Comment: This worked for me. Using rails 2.4.2p198, rails 4.2.8, bundler 1.17.3, ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 25):

I had this error appear with the same version of Ruby / Rails / SQLite that you specified in your question even after confirming that my gemfile has `gem 'sqlite3'`. I don't know what OS you have (which is why you were down-voted probably) but I am using Windows 7 x64.

In order to get the gem to be installed in my Rails application, I needed to edit the *Gemfile.lock* file to replace `sqlite3 (1.3.7-x86-mingw32)` with `sqlite3 (1.3.7)`

Then, after running bundle install I finally see in the output

```
Using sqlite3 (1.3.7)
```

Upon running rails server, I (finally) see the "Welcome aboard" page.

Comment: You can try to use `gem list sqlite3` and if you see more version from sqlite3 and for example would like to delete `sqlite3-mingw32` or simiar just use `gem uninstall sqlite3-mingw32`. You don't have to edit Gemfile.lock... but you have to repeat this steps if you use `bundle update` in your project.

Comment: When I run `gem list sqlite3` I see only one item: `sqlite3 (1.3.7)`. I originally ran `gem list` and that is when I saw the mismatch in versions. If you can help me understand why that would be an issue that would be appreciated - I am still a bit new at this. Generally speaking, it looks like 64bit Ruby on Windows has some issues; for example you can't use Capybara DSL inside of rspec with it because [nokogiri doesn't support 64bit Ruby on Windows yet](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864). (I am trying to get it all running as part of the (excellent) Rails tutorial.)

Comment: Paul, I totally understand your feeling... I've begun to learn Ruby on Windows as well, but I realized life is much more nicer with using a virtual machine and an ubuntu linux in it... Just drop me a private message if you need help.

Comment: I fixed the issue by doing this: edit Gemfile and change gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4' to gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4.2' and save, then run gem install sqlite3 -v '1.4.2', then run bundle update

Answer (score 17):

I'd the same problem on a x64 win 7.

Solution (for me):

1) Install sqlite3

> gem install sqlite3

2) Check the installed version

> gem list sqlite3

It gives me: sqlite3 (1.3.8 x64-mingw32)

3) Modify the Gemfile.lock

I change "sqlite3 (1.3.8-x86-mingw32)" by "sqlite3 (1.3.8-x64-mingw32)

It works :) Note that you to need add a "-" between the version number and the x64 in the Gemfile.lock

Xmass

Answer (score 13):

Another potential solution found on [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1406510/rails-server-gem-load-error-sqlite3)

I already had sqlite installed, but apparently since Feb 4, 2019 there's an issue with the sqlite3 v1.4.0 gem.

In the meantime, you can fall back to v1.3.6 by adding that version to the “sqlite3” line in your Gemfile, like so:

```
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6'
```

Hope this saves someone the time!

Answer (score 5):

1. Don't make another database global and then make sqlite3 specific to an environment on your gem file.
2. Use a previous gem.
3. Make sure you run `bundle install`, then `bundle update`, and lastly `bundle install`.

Your `Gemfile` might include entries like this:

```
group :development, :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.6'
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Run the commands in the following order

`sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`

`sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby`

`gem list`

After this command you will see the following versions of sqlite

sqlite3 (1.3.12)

sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)

Comment: After long tutorials on how to solve this problem, this simple solution worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For me it helped to put version after `gem 'sqlite3'` in gemfile, so it became `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'`.
Previously I tried to compile sqlite3, updated gem, etc... Rails wasn't able to "accept" it still, so finally defining the version helped.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple versions of sqlite3? Are you on Windows as well? I'm just curious. Everything worked without me having to redefine the gemfile. This is something that I would need to remember if for some reason Rails complains about it again.

Comment: That worked for me, too. I only have a single version of the sqlite3 gem but Rails (same config as OP) didn't see it until I included the version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

worked for me  sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev

Answer (score 1):

One small, but important side note for anyone running into this error.  Prior to version 1.4, Bundler could not understand 64 bit gems on Windows (https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2658) which explains why the 32bit versions were showing up in Gemfile.lock.

Manually changing:

`"sqlite3 (1.3.8-x86-mingw32" to "sqlite3 (1.3.8-x64-mingw32)"`

works if you're using an older version of bundler.  Bundler should be able to automatically figure things out now if you upgrade (1.5.2 currently works for me).

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line to your Gemfile, which is located in the root folder of your application

```
  gem 'sqlite3'
```

Comment: Thanks, maximus. I tried putting in gem sqlite3 as a new line, continued the lines with # gem sqlite3 and even # Use sqlite3# gem sqlite3 and #sqlite3, group :deployment.  Although I can only guess at what all that means...none of them worked. Once this is figured out, would I need to make these kind of changes for every app I make? Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention: I found the gem listed in Gemfile.lock

Comment: Update: I just saw this in Gemfile: "# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'"