# Cannot run Rails server on windows with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395812/segmentation-fault-when-compiling-mysql2-with-mingw) and tried the solution with no luck.

I have installed the most recent version of ruby, rails, and mysql. When I run rails server this is the error I get

I have spent about 5 hours reading everything I can find on this problem with no luck. This is my first time installing Ruby.

I have tried this on two separate machines with Windows 7

```
        Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ryork>cd Documents/sites/simple_cms

C:\Users\ryork\Documents\sites\simple_cms>rails server
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08) [x64-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0018 p:-9682704 s:0062 e:000061 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :require
c:0016 p:0083 s:0056 e:000055 TOP    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0054 e:000053 CFUNC  :require
c:0014 p:0037 s:0050 e:000049 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0047 e:000046 CFUNC  :each
c:0012 p:0055 s:0044 e:000043 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0037 e:000036 CFUNC  :each
c:0010 p:0030 s:0034 e:000033 METHOD C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0009 p:0013 s:0030 e:000029 METHOD C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132
c:0008 p:0049 s:0026 e:000025 TOP    C:/Users/ryork/Documents/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0024 e:000023 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0014 s:0020 e:000019 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0017 e:000016 CFUNC  :tap
c:0004 p:0586 s:0014 e:000013 TOP    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require
c:0002 p:0034 s:0004 E:001078 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:000a18 TOP    [FINISH]

bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:76:in `require'
C:/Users/ryork/Documents/sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(NtWaitForSingleObject+0xa) [0x00000000774712FA]
C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x9c) [0x000007FEFD4810DC]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0x9d) [0x000000006F28669D]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x838) [0x000000006F141EE8]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_bug+0x45) [0x000000006F142C95]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x18c) [0x000000006F20B12C]
 [0x0000000000401A85]
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_C_specific_handler+0x9c) [0x00000000774385C8]
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlDecodePointer+0xad) [0x0000000077449D2D]
C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlUnwindEx+0xbbf) [0x00000000774391CF]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
    2 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    3 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
    4 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
    5 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    6 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    7 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    8 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    9 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
   10 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   12 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   13 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   14 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
   15 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/utf_16le.so
   16 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
   17 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   18 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   19 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   20 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   21 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   22 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/single_byte.so
   23 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   24 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   25 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/pathname.so
   26 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
   27 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/constants.rb
   28 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   29 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/etc.so
   30 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   31 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   32 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
   33 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   34 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
   35 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
   36 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   37 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   38 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   39 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/version.rb
   40 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb
   41 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/settings.rb
   42 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/digest.so
   43 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
   44 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/digest/sha1.so
   45 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
   46 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb
   47 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
   48 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
   49 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   50 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source.rb
   51 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
   52 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
   53 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
   54 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
   55 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
   56 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
   57 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   58 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
   59 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
   60 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
   61 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
   62 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
   63 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
   64 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/socket.so
   65 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
   66 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/fcntl.so
   67 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   68 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so
   69 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
   70 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
   71 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/stringio.so
   72 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
   73 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
   74 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
   75 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
   76 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
   77 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
   78 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb
   79 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/fiddle.so
   80 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/function.rb
   81 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/closure.rb
   82 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle.rb
   83 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/value.rb
   84 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/pack.rb
   85 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/struct.rb
   86 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/cparser.rb
   87 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/import.rb
   88 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb
   89 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/resolv.rb
   90 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/resolv.rb
   91 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
   92 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
   93 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
   94 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
   95 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
   96 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/strscan.so
   97 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
   98 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
   99 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
  100 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
  101 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb
  102 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
  103 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
  104 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/environment.rb
  105 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
  106 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/index.rb
  107 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
  108 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
  109 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
  110 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb
  111 C:/Users/ryork/Documents/sites/simple_cms/config/boot.rb
  112 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/optparse.rb
  113 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/version.rb
  114 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb
  115 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/synchronized_delegator.rb
  116 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe.rb
  117 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb
  118 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb
  119 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb
  120 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb
  121 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/version.rb
  122 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb
  123 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb
  124 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n.rb
  125 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
  126 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.11/lib/i18n/config.rb
  127 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/i18n.rb
  128 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb
  129 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/mri_cache_backend.rb
  130 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.3.4/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb
  131 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb
  132 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflections.rb
  133 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb
  134 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb
  135 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/version.rb
  136 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb
  137 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb
  138 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb
  139 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb
  140 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb
  141 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/logger.rb
  142 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support.rb
  143 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb
  144 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb
  145 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method.rb
  146 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb
  147 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb
  148 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/singleton.rb
  149 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb
  150 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb

  4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller.rb
  402 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/request.rb
  403 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/response.rb
  404 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/filter_redirect.rb
  405 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/cache.rb
  406 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/response.rb
  407 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/live.rb
  408 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/hash_with_indifferent_access.rb
  409 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/indifferent_access.rb
  410 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/proc.rb
  411 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/rescuable.rb
  412 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/http/upload.rb
  413 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/mock_session.rb
  414 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/cookie_jar.rb
  415 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/mock_digest_request.rb
  416 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/utils.rb
  417 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/methods.rb
  418 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test/uploaded_file.rb
  419 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.2/lib/rack/test.rb
  420 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb
  421 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/erb.rb
  422 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/output_safety.rb
  423 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view.rb
  424 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/vendor/html-scanner.rb
  425 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/load_error.rb
  426 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/name_error.rb
  427 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/uri.rb
  428 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller.rb
  429 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/railtie.rb
  430 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb
  431 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/railties/helpers.rb
  432 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb
  433 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/railtie.rb
  434 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/version.rb
  435 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/delegating_attributes.rb
  436 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/reachable.rb
  437 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb
  438 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/class.rb
  439 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer.rb
  440 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.0/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb
  441 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb
  442 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/version.rb
  443 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike.rb
  444 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb
  445 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/string.rb
  446 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/erb.rb
  447 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/etanni.rb
  448 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/haml.rb
  449 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/css.rb
  450 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/csv.rb
  451 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/coffee.rb
  452 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/nokogiri.rb
  453 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/builder.rb
  454 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markaby.rb
  455 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/liquid.rb
  456 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/radius.rb
  457 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markdown.rb
  458 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/textile.rb
  459 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/rdoc.rb
  460 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/wiki.rb
  461 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/yajl.rb
  462 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/asciidoc.rb
  463 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/plain.rb
  464 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt.rb
  465 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/eco_template.rb
  466 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/ejs_template.rb
  467 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/jst_processor.rb
  468 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/utils.rb
  469 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/engines.rb
  470 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/mime.rb
  471 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/mime.rb
  472 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processor.rb
  473 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processing.rb
  474 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb
  475 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/paths.rb
  476 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/normalized_array.rb
  477 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/extensions.rb
  478 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb
  479 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/paths.rb
  480 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/trail.rb
  481 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb
  482 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb
  483 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/safety_colons.rb
  484 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/charset_normalizer.rb
  485 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb
  486 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb
  487 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/closure_compressor.rb
  488 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb
  489 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/sass_template.rb
  490 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/scss_template.rb
  491 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets.rb
  492 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb
  493 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/active_model_helper.rb
  494 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/zlib.so
  495 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb
  496 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb
  497 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb
  498 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb
  499 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/atom_feed_helper.rb
  500 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb
  501 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb
  502 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb
  503 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb
  504 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb
  505 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb
  506 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb
  507 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb
  508 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb
  509 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb
  510 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb
  511 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb
  512 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/tags.rb
  513 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/model_naming.rb
  514 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb
  515 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb
  516 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb
  517 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb
  518 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/output_safety_helper.rb
  519 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
  520 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module.rb
  521 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb
  522 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/record_tag_helper.rb
  523 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb
  524 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb
  525 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/helpers.rb
  526 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb
  527 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb
  528 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb
  529 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb
  530 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/all.rb
  531 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb
  532 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/version.rb
  533 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/error.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

C:\Users\ryork\Documents\sites\simple_cms>
```

Comment: You should probably post the full error output, this one it cut off.

Comment: I added the code from the top, there are more errors than space in Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

Your bug seems to be caused by the MySQL gem segfaulting, possibly a buggy version for your OS version.

Issues like this can require a lot of trial and error with different versions. It might be faster if you try installing via RailsInstaller (http://railsinstaller.org) or set up Vagrant and use an off-the-shelf Rails recipe (https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development).