# How can I run rails with Sqlite3 on Mac? I'm getting " gem is not loaded" but it was included on Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, gemfile

I would like to create a new rails app using Sqlite but I have found some issues. 
I am using `Rails 5.0.7.1` properly installed and `gem 'sqlite3'` included in my Gemfile. The version of sqlite3 in my system (Mac OS) is `3.24.0 2018-06-04 14:10:15 95fbac39baaab1c3a84fdfc82ccb7f42398b2e92f18a2a57bce1d4a713cbaapl`

Running the rails server and accessing to my localhost:3000 give me the error:

> Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded.
>   Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the
>   minimum required by ActiveRecord).

The gem was installed running bundle install and I can see it in my Gemfile.lock `sqlite3 (1.4.0)`

I don't know what is the issue. Anyone could help me? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had issues with sqlite3(1.4.0) with the older version of ruby/rails(2.5/5.2). You can try specifying the lower version of sqlite3 in **Gemfile** and running the bundle again.

```
 gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.13'
```

Possible duplicate of [Ruby on Rails - "Add 'gem sqlite3'' to your Gemfile"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17350837/ruby-on-rails-add-gem-sqlite3-to-your-gemfile)

Comment: Indeed, I have specified the gem version (gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.3.6') in my Gemfile and it's working fine. The problem was a conflicts between sqlite versions. I had noticed that when trying to create the database I got this: 
`Gem::LoadError: can't activate sqlite3 (~> 1.3.6), already activated sqlite3-1.4.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.`
Then, specifying the version and executing bundle update finally works.

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @JoseMariaRoman: 1.3.6 didn't work for me but 1.3.13 does. I guess, this may have something to do with recent OS upgrade to Mojave.